# javascript Loop To select specific item

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am trying to get the right div under each navigation item to animate, instead of all of them with the class "navItemUnder" -- You can see in this codePen what I mean, when you hover over one of the navigation items.

I want a way to select only one line under the right nav item, while keeping the way we have the HTML in-tact.

codePen: http://codepen.io/celli/pen/bpRLRM

```
$(".navItem").hover(over, out);
function over(){
TweenMax.to(".navItemUnder", 1, {opacity:1.0, scaleX:1,     ease:Expo.easeOut})
}
function out(){
TweenMax.to(".navItemUnder", 1, {opacity:0.0, scaleX:.1,     ease:Expo.easeOut})
}
```

Comment: the issue is that you apply the tweenMax.to to all .navItemUnder elements, all of them.

You might want to add an index class or find the right .navItemUnder respectively

Comment: have a look at this https://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: As @mahatmanich said, you can use a combination of `.index()` and `.eq()` to animate only the desired element. **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53ps8d5b/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **id** attribute to differentiate the elements:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWyRjg

```js
var activeItem;

TweenMax.set(".navItemUnder", {
  opacity: 0,
  scaleX: .1,
  transformOrigin: "top left"
})

$(".navItem").hover(over, out);

function over(e) {
  activeItem = e.toElement.id;
  TweenMax.to("#" + activeItem + "_under", 1, {
    opacity: 1.0,
    scaleX: 1,
    ease: Expo.easeOut
  })
}

function out(e) {
  TweenMax.to("#" + activeItem + "_under", 1, {
    opacity: 0.0,
    scaleX: .1,
    ease: Expo.easeOut
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.lines {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 4px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  text-align: center;
}
.navItem {
  width: 46px;
  height: 26px;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navItemUnder {
  width: 46px;
  height: 2px;
  background: green;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="navItem" id="item1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="navItem" id="item2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="navItem" id="item3">Item 3</li>
    <li class="navItem" id="item4">Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="lines">
  <ul>
    <li class="navItemUnder" id="item1_under"></li>
    <li class="navItemUnder" id="item2_under"></li>
    <li class="navItemUnder" id="item3_under"></li>
    <li class="navItemUnder" id="item4_under"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```